# Looking for simple function which will produce this derivative

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I am trying to find a simple function $f(x, y)$ such that its derivative will have the form 
$$
f' = (1 - H) y dx + H x dy.
$$
where $H$ is some constant.

The coefficients of the two terms make it hard to apply the product rule. I tried integrating by parts and the quotient rule, but i have not had much success.

Any suggestions or help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Do not confuse function and differentials. You wrote : $$f' = (1 - H) y dx + H x dy.$$ This is a non-sens since the left term is a function which cannot be equal to an infinitesimal term on the right. I suppose that you mean : $$df = (1 - H) y dx + H x dy$$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You know that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}= (1-H)y$. Integrating with respect to $dx$, you get
$$
f = (1-H)xy+C(y)\tag 1
$$
Note that the constant which appears in integration can depend on $y$. Doing the same with the $y$ component,
$$
f = Hxy + D(x)\tag2
$$
Equating these two, you can show that $H=1/2$ and $C(y)=D(x)=K$ for some constant $K$.

---

**Edit:** For a proof that the only possible $H$ is $H=1/2$, take equation (1) and compute $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x\partial y}$ of both sides. You get that $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y}=1-H$. Doing the same with equation (2), you get $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x\partial y}=H$. This means $H=1-H$, so $H=1/2$.

Comment: what is a valid example of $f$ then ? Also $H$ is mean to be a constant.

Comment: Take the conclusions in my last sentence, and plug them in to the equation $f=(1-H)xy+C(y)$. $K$ is arbitrary constant, so choose it to be whatever you want (perhaps 0).

Comment: I do not think that produces the derivative i am after, Can you please elaborate how u are getting that answer from such a choice of $f$.

Comment: Perhaps I am confused by your notation. I was interpreting the statement "$f'=(1-H)y\,dx+Hx\,dy$" to mean that the gradient of $f$ was equal to $((1-H)y,Hx)$, which is equivalent to saying $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=(1-H)y$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=Hx$. This implies that one solution is $f(x,y)=\frac12xy$, and you can verify this satisfies those two equations.

Comment: Your solution is only for the case $H = \frac{1}{2}$, I am after a solution with $H$. Do you know how we can get that ?

Comment: Ah, I see. My method shows that a solution only exists when $H=1/2$. There are no solutions for any other $H$.

Comment: I suspected the same, although i am not convinced that there can not be any other solutions. How can we see that ?

Comment: @ComicBookGuy See edit